# How to get original image paths within iphotos library mac swift

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, photos, iphoto

I am trying to get original file path of images from photos library. By using NSOpenPAnel i am able to get the photos library path i.e file:///Users/betteruse/Pictures/Photos%20Library.photoslibrary

I want to traverse the file and retrive the contents in Master folder. I am doing it in swift and stuck at this point. Please help me with this.

Answer (score -1):

don't know what's swift but via finder u can right click on library file and open it as a package , u can make an alias of Masters, orbu can get it via terminal also with simple and usual cmds as cd and ls.